# show that every compact subset in a normed space is closed but the converse need not to be true

Tags: functional-analysis

I understand that every compact subset in a normed space is closed but I don't understand why converse is not true

Comment: Any compact subset must also be bounded.

Comment: Absolutely. A strategy for the OP would be to exhibit a closed unbounded subset of the normed space ; this would give a counter-example for the converse.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any normed space, choose $x\in X$ non-zero, and let $C=\{\lambda x:\lambda\geq 0\}\subset X$.  Then $C$ is a closed subset of $X$, but it is not compact, as the sequence $(x_n)$ in $C$ given by $x_n=nx$ has no convergent subsequence.